# Scramble each digit of the int a and print out the biggest possible integer

Tags: java, random, shuffle

I’m stuck here. Do I just keep making new strings and turn them to int or us there a faster better way?

````
public void biggest(int a){
       int random;
       String aS = String.valueOf(a);
       int ah=9;
       if (a<10)
             System.out.println(a);
       for(int i= 0;i<aS.length();i++){
            String firstNum = aS.substring(i,i+1);
            for (int j = ah; j > Integer.parseInt(firstNum); j--){
                System.out.println(ah);
            
            }
            }
    } ```
````

Comment: Forget the code to start with. If I gave you the number "2519" and asked you to make the biggest number you could with those digits, would you try lots of different numbers, or would you know the result immediately? If you'd know it immediately, how would you do that? Once you've worked that out, you just need to turn that into code...

Comment: User has to provide input. It can be 140 it can be 300484

Comment: Okay, so again, ignore the code: if someone gave you the number 140, how would you respond? What about 300484? What would your mental process be?

Comment: Turn int to string, make substrings and turn them back to int. Then do if statement and compare numbers from higher to lower

Comment: Would you really make multiple substrings? Looking at "300484" as an example, I can tell you immediately that the highest number is "844300" without trying any other strings. I suspect you would have done too. Maybe work a few examples out on a whiteboard...

Comment: Oh, I’m so sorry I forgot to specify, I can not use array, I can only use (if,while, for)

Comment: This is the code I came up with till this point ```public void biggest(int a){
       int random;
       String aS = String.valueOf(a);
       
       if (a<10)
             System.out.println(a);
       for(int i= 0;i<aS.length();i++){
            String firstNum = aS.substring(i,i+1);
            for (int ah = 9; ah <= Integer.parseInt(firstNum);i++){
            
                if(Integer.parseInt(firstNum) == ah)
                System.out.print(firstNum);
                else
                ah--;
            }
            
            }
            
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use conversion to String in this case, you can get the digits from the input number by getting a remainder by modulo 10, then dividing the input number by 10 and repeat it while the number > 0.

Each digit should be stored in an array or list.

To get the biggest number of these digits you should just sort them (standard facilities such as `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` will do fine) and then "re-assemble" the biggest number from the lowest digit by multiplying it by 1, 10, 100, etc. and summing up.

So, plain implementation could be as follows:

```java
public static int biggestPlain(int a) {
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
    while (a > 0) {
        digits.add(a % 10);
        a /= 10;
    }
    Collections.sort(digits);
    int p = 1;
    int num = 0;
    for (int digit : digits) {
        num += p * digit;
        p *= 10;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Also, this task can be implemented using Stream API and lambda and applying the same approach:

```java
public static int biggestStream(int a) {

    AtomicInteger p = new AtomicInteger(1); // accumulate powers of 10

    return IntStream.iterate(a, n -> n > 0, n -> n / 10) // divide input number by 10 while it > 0
                    .map(i -> (i % 10)) // get the digit
                    .sorted() // sort (the lower digits first)
                    .map(i -> p.getAndUpdate((x) -> x * 10) * i) // same as p * digit above
                    .sum(); // get the result number
}
```

**Update**
Iterate over digits from '9' till '0' and check if they are available in the string presentation of the input number.

`String`-based solution:

```java
public static void biggest(int a) {

    String aS = String.valueOf(a);
    if (a < 10) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    String num = "";
    int count = 0;
    out: for (char i = '9'; i >= '0'; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < aS.length(); j++) {
            char digit = aS.charAt(j);
            if (digit == i) {
                num += digit;
                if (++count == aS.length()) {
                    break out;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(num + " / " + Integer.parseInt(num));
}
```

Comment: Oh, I’m so sorry I forgot to specify, I can not use array, I can only use (if,while, for)

Comment: So you need to do this using String which is based on `char` array? :)  The stream solution does not use array but I think it may not be good for you either.

Comment: So I’m just starting to learn Java and I need to figure out how to do this with basic java, as I said if, while, for, and transformation between string and int

Comment: This is perfect but I can’t use index either:(

Comment: You mean `indexOf`? That's not a big problem

Comment: Yeah if you could edit out indexOf that would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int biggest(int num) {
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;

    int res = 0;

    if (num > 0) {
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
            res = update(res, i, num);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            res = update(res, i, num);

        res *= -1;
    }

    return res;
}

private static int update(int res, int i, int n) {
    n = Math.abs(n);

    while (n > 0) {
        if (n % 10 == i)
            res = res * 10 + i;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return res;
}
```

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(biggest(12341234));  // 44332211
System.out.println(biggest(-12341234)); // -11223344
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to count how many 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 values you have and then assemble them back together into a number knowing the digits will always be in descending order (9, 8, 7, ..., 0).  The easy way to do this is with an array.  Since this is a homework assignment the hard way (without using an array as per the requirement you added in a comment) is to use a variable counter per digit.

```
public class so64125767 {
    public static int biggestBuckets(int a) {
        int[] buckets = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        while (a > 0) {
            buckets[a % 10]++;
            a /= 10;
        }

        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buckets[i]; j++) {
                num *= 10;
                num += i;
            }
        }

        return num;
    }

    public static int biggestBucketsVar(int a) {
        int zero = 0;
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        int five = 0;
        int six = 0;
        int seven = 0;
        int eight = 0;
        int nine = 0;

        while (a > 0) {
            switch (a % 10) {
            case 0:
                zero++;
                break;
            case 1:
                one++;
                break;
            case 2:
                two++;
                break;
            case 3:
                three++;
                break;
            case 4:
                four++;
                break;
            case 5:
                five++;
                break;
            case 6:
                six++;
                break;
            case 7:
                seven++;
                break;
            case 8:
                eight++;
                break;
            case 9:
                nine++;
                break;
            }
            a /= 10;
        }

        int num = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < nine; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 9;
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < eight; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 8;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < seven; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 7;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < six; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 6;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < five; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 5;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < four; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 4;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < three; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 3;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < two; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 2;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < one; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            num += 1;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < zero; j++) {
            num *= 10;
            // num += 0;
        }

        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(biggestBuckets(237428379));
        System.out.println(biggestBucketsVar(237428379));
        -- 987743322
    }
}
```

I'm also going to bet if you benchmark these results along with the other suggestions (using String or Collections) you'll find this method scales the best (imagine if you accepted numbers beyond the size of an int).

Answer (score -1):

```
    String useMe = Integer.toString(argumentOne);
    int rMe = argumentOne;
 
    int x = 0;
    while (x != 1000) {
      int i = 0;
      String returnMe = "";
      String inUse = useMe;
      while (i != useMe.length()) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(inUse.length());
        returnMe = returnMe + inUse.charAt(index);
        inUse = inUse.substring(0, index) + inUse.substring(index + 1);
        i++;
      }
      if (Integer.parseInt(returnMe) > rMe) {
        rMe = Integer.parseInt(returnMe);
      }
      x++;
    }
 
    System.out.print( rMe );
 
  }
```

Comment: It does not provide correct answers, it doubles the number: `123` -> `321321`, etc.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.