# How do I rearrange an integer so that it is rearranged as its highest possible value in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, methods

For example, if someone inserts 34603, the output would be 64330. I've started this problem already but I can not think of a solution that works. Also, since this is an assignment, my instructor told me that arrays are not allowed. Here is what I have thus far:

```java
public class loops{
    loops(){}
    public void biggest(int a){
        String as = Integer.toString(a);
        int index=0;
        int asl = as.length();
        while(index<asl){
            String num1 = as.substring(index);
            String num2 = as.substring((index+1));
            int con1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
            int con2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
        
               if(con1<con2){
                   System.out.println("con2: "+con2);
               }
               if(con1>con2){
                   System.out.println("con1: "+con1);
               }
               
            System.out.println("added: "+con1+" "+con2);
            
            index++;
        }
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        loops x = new loops();
        x.biggest(4583);        
     }
}
```

I would appreciate any and all help/hints, for I am truly lost on this one.

Comment: Array not allowed mean you can use List maybe ? (Probably not)

Comment: Oh no lists or dictionaries allowed either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scramble each digit of the int a and print out the biggest possible integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125767/scramble-each-digit-of-the-int-a-and-print-out-the-biggest-possible-integer)  Almost the same question was asked just yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be reasonably obvious that the largest possible result is obtained by arranging the digits in descending order.  One of the easier and more efficient ways of doing that would be with a counting sort, but the usual forms of that involve using arrays or array-equivalents to accumulate the counts.

So standard Counting Sort is out, along with all standard sort routines aimed at rearranging sequences of items.  But you can still take your inspiration from Counting Sort.  For example, figure out how many 9 digits are in the input, and form a number from that many 9s.  Then figure out how many 8s and append them.  Then how many 7s, *etc*.  "Appending" digits to a number can be done arithmetically, so the whole procedure can be done without an array or array equivalent, even if we consider Strings to be array equivalents (as we should).

Details are left as the exercise they are intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer the question directly for you but suggest some ideas to help you.

1. you need to sort the integers in place - ie no arrays/no lists.. just iterate over the integer as a string which you're doing correctly, and progressively swap values so that you end up with a sorted numerical value.
2. thinking of various sort algorithms, quicksort, mergesort, bubble sort, etc. you effectively pick one of these algorithms and try to implement it.
3. start with the basic examples for integers to sort and iteratively develop your code to successively generate the correct answer... as test cases try:

   1. no number at all... `null`
   2. then the empty string `""`
   3. then a single digit, so a number `0-9`
   4. Next two digits both in order, then out of the sort order
   5. then 3 digits in/out of order

   Once you've implemented for 3 digits you should be able to generate your solution for any number of digits.

Note: if you use `Integer` as the input data type, you will be limited to being able to take a maximum integer value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which isn't that large). Try to treat the input argument as a `String` and the individual digits as integers for the comparison (which you are already doing), this way you'll be able to process a much larger input.

Answer (score 0):

**import java.util.ArrayList;**
**import java.util.Collections;**

public class loops{
loops(){}

```
public void biggest(int a){
    String as = Integer.toString(a);
    int index=0;
    int index2=1;
    int asl = as.length();
    ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    while(index<asl){
      String num1 = as.substring(index,index2);
      int con1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
      lista.add(con1);
      index++;
      index2++;
    }
    //order list
    Collections.sort(lista);
    Collections.reverse(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);
    //concatenate numbers

}

 public static void main(String []args){
    loops x = new loops();
    x.biggest(34603);        
 }
```

}

**anything consult back. **

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with this. It's not the prettiest solution, I recognize that, but it DOES work. Have a look:

```java
public class loops{
    public int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;
    public loops(){}

public void biggest(int a){
        String as = Integer.toString(a);
        int index=0;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        e = 0;
        f = 0;
        g = 0;
        h = 0;
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        int asl = as.length();
        while(index<asl){
            String num3 = as.substring(index,(index+1));
            int con3 = Integer.parseInt(num3);
            if(con3==9){a++;}
            if(con3==8){b++;}
            if(con3==7){c++;}
            if(con3==6){d++;}
            if(con3==5){e++;}
            if(con3==4){f++;}
            if(con3==3){g++;}
            if(con3==2){h++;}
            if(con3==1){i++;}
            if(con3==0){j++;}
               index++;
            }

         for(int z=0;z<a;z++){
          System.out.print("9");
          }
          for(int y=0;y<b;y++){
          System.out.print("8");
          }
          for(int x=0;x<c;x++){
          System.out.print("7");
          }
          for(int w=0;w<d;w++){
          System.out.print("6");
          }
          for(int v=0;v<e;v++){
          System.out.print("5");
          }
          for(int u=0;u<f;u++){
          System.out.print("4");
          }
          for(int t=0;t<g;t++){
          System.out.print("3");
          }
          for(int s=0;s<h;s++){
          System.out.print("2");
          }
          for(int r=0;r<i;r++){
          System.out.print("1");
          }
          for(int q=0;q<j;q++){
          System.out.print("0");
          }
public static void main(String []args){
        loops x = new loops();
        x.biggest(45683408); 
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If arrays aren't allowed, then I don't think strings should be allowed either:

```
static void biggest(int n)
{
    long counts=0;
    for(; n>0; n/=10)
    {
        counts += 1L<<((n%10)*4);
    }
    long result=0;
    for (long digit=9; digit>=0; --digit)
    {
        for(long rep=(counts>>(digit*4))&15; rep>0; --rep)
        {
            result = result*10 + digit;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```